# Area charts in Highcharts: min and minPadding for y-axis

Tags: highcharts

I would like some help with Area chart. If the series values are not 0.0, the minimum value of the chart always set into 0, and it's correctly on the bottom of the chart (ie) y-axis:

I try to set

{
   min: 0,
   minPadding:0
}
on the y-axis, but it doesn't work. Obviously I can't set a max value because I have a dynamic data. How can I solve this?

I have tried above cases in line charts its working properly, but not in Area charts?

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle to better assist you!

Comment: It is unclear what your actual question/problem is. What do you actually want, and what about it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is to set a max (or min) dynamically, you can use event to set dynamically max and min:

```
var newMaxValue=60000000;
var newMinValue=10000000;
```

...

```
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var check = $('#container').highcharts();
        check.yAxis[0].setExtremes(newMinValue, newMaxValue);
    }
```

Check the example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/5mcvgptf/)):

```
$(function() {
var newMaxValue=60000000;
var newMinValue=10000000;
  $('#container').highcharts({

      chart: {
      type: 'area',

      events: {
        load: function() {
          var check = $('#container').highcharts();
            check.yAxis[0].setExtremes(newMinValue, newMaxValue);

        }
      }
    },


    series: [{
      "data": [{
        "y": 198975.14,

      }, {
        "y": 15031755.47,

      }, {
        "y": 21374471.88,
      }],
      "name": "Income Statement",
      "yAxis": 0
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: I have try to get the extremes for y-axis
var ex = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
So, it returns 
{
 min: 0, 
 max: 15000, 
 dataMin: 0, 
 dataMax: 13222.7109375 
}
In my dataMax value is always above 10000. Then, How do I set y-axis min value as dynamically for this case?

If i have to set min=10000000, its working. But i have a doubt on this, why we are setting min value as 10000000 instead of setting min=0, it is necessary to set.

Comment: I set up the demo above just as an example, please share your data to better assist you!

Comment: you have set the min and max value as hardcoded                                 var newMaxValue=60000000;
var newMinValue=10000000;                                                                                                                                                                                    How to take min and max value as dynamically?

Comment: You can read min/max from any other source and set it to your min/max. Could you please try to set threshold to null, it may solves your issue, check this link :http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/area-threshold/