# How to make the Y Axis values not start from 0 in highcharts? How to display forcefully display the last category data on X axis in HighCharts ?

Tags: highcharts

So, here I am stuck with two things.Even after enough brainstorming, I couldn't figure out what parameters need to be changes to make my graph display the data as desired. 
Here's the output of my graph: [MY Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwdEH.jpg). I want the output to be something like this: [Desired Price Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uVEF.jpg)

There are basically 2 things which I want to make it work. 
Firstly,I guess, making to Y label to not start from 0 will make the graph work.But I couldn't figure which parameter I need to change.

Secondly, for X Axis data, I am passing an array of dates as Category to XAxis series. And I want to display dates at the interval of seven days. I have successfully implemented that. The issue which I am facing is, I want to forcefully display the today's date. Today's date is the last element in the XAxisData Array of my code which I am passing to the 'categories' for X Axis. So, my question here is, how do I forcefully display the last element of the A Axis categories? (optional question)Is there a better way to do that, by using datetime? 
Here's my code for the graph:

```
function setPriceParameterAndDisplay(){
document.getElementById('container').style.visibility='visible';
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: StockHeading ,
    },
    subtitle: {
         text: '<a style=\"color:blue;\" href=\"https://www.alphavantage.co\">Source: Alpha Vantage</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: XAxisData,
          minTickInterval: 6,

   showLastLabel: true,

    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Stock Price',
        },
         },{
        title: {
            text: 'Volume '
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}m',
        },
        opposite:true,

    }],
    plotOptions: {
    label: {
    enabled: false,
},
        line: {

            enableMouseTracking: true
        },
        series: {
        marker: {
                enabled: false
            },}
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    series: [{
        name: '".$symbol."',
        label: {
    enabled: false,
},
        type: 'area',
        color: '#F66464',
        data: PriceData,
        tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }

    }, {
        name: '".$symbol." Volume' ,
        label: {
    enabled: false,
},
        type: 'column',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
         yAxis: 1,
        data: StockVolume,
        tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }


    }]
});}
```

Comment: If you add part of the datainput, it makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot. That said, for the y-axis issue, have a look at this question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819525/highcharts-fill-area-point-interval-issue

Comment: Kamil is correct. You should accept his answer.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Make area series not to start from zero (y axis)**

You need to specify a `threshold` property for this series. By default it's `0` and that's the cause of your problem.

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.threshold

---

**2. Force the x axis label to be always displayed for the last point**

By default Highcharts automatically calculates and decides which ticks to show. Labels appear where the ticks do. So to make sure that some specific tick appears on the axis use `tickPosition` (define all ticks manually) or `tickPositioner` (modify the ticks created by Highcharts before passing them to the chart constructor).

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner